# Module "undefined" is missing from the asset registry

Tags: react-native, expo, warnings

I can't find where this error is coming from ... any advices ? I am using expo sdk 41
I get this error on launching the app . I checked my icon and it is good png quality 52*52...

````
Module "undefined" is missing from the asset registry
at node_modules\expo-asset\build\Asset.js:53:18 in fromModule
at App.js:34:11 in images.map$argument_0
at [native code]:null in map
at App.js:30:9 in cacheImages
at App.js:46:33 in _loadResourcesAsync
at node_modules\expo-app-loading\build\AppLoading.js:17:4 in startLoadingAppResourcesAsync
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js:463:6 in initializePromise
at node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js:875:38 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\expo-app-loading\build\AppLoading.js:17:4 in startLoadingAppResourcesAsync
at node_modules\expo-app-loading\build\AppLoading.js:9:8 in componentDidMount
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15688:12 in commitLifeCycles
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
at [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20527:14 in updateContainer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21068:17 in render
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:54:4 in renderApplication
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:213:4 in runApplication
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue```
````

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is when you call the method below `Asset.fromModule(uri)` (from expo-asset). uri CANNOT be undefined. I solved it just simply replace it to a valid string.